# Having trouble making a PHP cookie stick

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I'm trying to create a temporary login system for a site. I'm using cookies rather than a database as it is merely for FED testing but for some reason my cookies are not sticking :(

I know I'm posting fine because the header function works

```
if ($_POST['login'] == 1) {
    if (($user=="name") && ($pass=="secret")) {  
        setcookie("seeker", "1", time()+3600); 
        header('Location: ../index.php?');
    } else echo '<i>Incorrect username/password.</i>';
}
```

Comment: Is the cookie not there or does it ever get set? what does "not sticking" mean?

Comment: How do you know the cookies are not sticking? What does `var_dump($_COOKIE);` show?

Comment: I know it's not sticking because I have no cookies in my browser. I have a separate piece of code that does something if the cookie exists and thats not happening

Comment: Are you outputting anything to the screen before setting the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Try a full cookie setting with a larger expiry value:

```
setcookie('seeker', 1, time()+86400, '/', '.example.com');
```

The path setting may be the reason. If you're setting the cookie in a script in `example.com/subdir/script.php`, then the cookie will using `/subdir` as its path, and not show up for scripts running in different directories.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider using [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). It will set the cookies for you automatically.